# Is there any way to change User-Agent of Apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, http-headers

I am trying to change `User-Agent`. But It seems like I can't change it.

I implemented like this:

```
{
'User-Agent': "my spreadsheet" 
}
```

the value above passes API function like this:

```
function API(m_headers, method, data){
  var options = {
    'headers': m_headers,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : false,
    'method' : method,
    'payload' : data
  };

  var url = base_url+api;
  try{
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  }catch(e){
      return url+"\n"+JSON.stringify(e);
  }
}
```

And I get `Attribute provided with invalid value in Google Apps Script` error.

```
{"message":"Attribute provided with invalid value: headers","name":"Exception","fileName":"Code","lineNumber":42,"stack":"\tat Code:42 (API)\n"}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't think you can change themm

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The number of supported consistent headers is strictly limited.